# Meteor not being able to connect to prerender.io server

Tags: javascript, meteor, prerender

I have set up a prerender server on my local machine.

It is on port 3033 and it seems to display a rendered version of my meteor site when I type this in

```
curl http://localhost:3033/http://localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=
```

Knowing that my prerender site works, I'm trying to set it up so that if I go to

```
curl http://localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=
```

it should give me my Meteor site.

I'm using this package (https://github.com/dfischer/meteor-prerenderio) and I've got this line in my settings.json file

```
  "PrerenderIO": {
    "prerenderServiceUrl": "http://localhost:3033/"
  }
```

However, when I run

```
curl http://localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=
```

it returns nothing and I'm getting this message shown up on my meteor server log

```
res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead
```

and it doesn't seem to be hitting the prerender server.

What is this message and why aren't I able to hit the prerender server?

Comment: When you say "it returns nothing", do you mean you see a blank page? What status code are you seeing? Do you see any info in the console of your prerender server?

Comment: @prerender.io - it was returning absolutely nothing but it wasn't hitting the server. It turns out that in this package I needed to actually specify a token string even on a local server. I've submitted a pull request to see if the author will change this but the issue can be easily overcome by just specifying a dummy token string.